# Browser just downloads page when I set the header to xml/text

Tags: php, xml

I have a php file where everything works fine, but If I set the header to:

```
header("Content-type: xml/text");
```

Like it should be, my browser just tries to download it. It works with curl, but not Safari. It's weird because I have a lot of files that have that header on my server and they work, I even created a test php and set the header to that and it worked. How can I debug why that specfic page downloads when I set the header?

Comment: It's not `xml/text` - it should be `text/html` or `text/xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
```

`text/xml` is correct mime-type.  Different user agents likely handle the invalid `xml/text` mime type differently, resulting in weirdness.

(More precisely, use `text/xml` if there is some intention that the XML could be readable by a human and use `application/xml` if not.  Both these two are valid mime types for XML.)

Comment: This worked, thanks. But the XML isn't meant to be read by anyone except me or the server, I just don't want it to be downloaded to everyone who visits the page. The output of this one is not different though so it's okay.